# user lost sudo permissions after sudo password update

Tags: 20.04, sudo

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I no longer can run any command with `sudo`. When logged in from terminal, I have verified that I am in the `sudo` group.

```
jianwu@localhost:/usr/bin$ sudo whoami
root
```

If I run a command say

```
jianwu@localhost:/usr/bin$ sudo supervisorctl restart all
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/supervisorctl: Permission denied
```

If I check the supervisorctl permission

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         979 Sep 11  2020  supervisorctl
```

The sudo permission right now is

```
-rwsr-xr-x  1 root root      232408 Feb 14 11:48  sudo
```

supervisorctl is not the only command that no longer works. Command like

```
sudo apt-get update
```

no longer works either and outputs

```
jianwu@localhost:/usr/bin$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Hit:2 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Fetched 110 kB in 4s (31.4 kB/s)   
sh: 1: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: Permission denied
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Can this issue be related to change of my sudo password that occured one day before? I am using the server from Linode's service and one day before I updated the sudo password.

Comment: What recent changes did you make on your system?

Comment: Changed the root password. I changed it yesterday

Comment: What is the 'root password'? The root account is normally disabled on Ubuntu.

Comment: It is a server from Linode. There is a place from their website allowing one to change the root password for the disk.

Comment: All that information needs to go in your question. Don't withhold important info when asking for help.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I just updated the post with additional information. Didn't thought it was relevant at the time I wrote the post